# Range had no valid blocks to process with Beacon set up on Prysm

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, error, prysm

While setting up the beacon with Prysm, I am getting the error `Range had no valid blocks to process`

I am trying to set up the node for Ethereum. I would really appreciate the help. The official guides do not provide insight to this error